# UIImageView animations slow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I've got a `UIImageView` with about 10 full-screen jpegs, totalling about 128k. Throwing these into the`UIImageView` with `setAnimationImages` works like a champion in the emulator until I try to run it on the iPhone which results in a fail. Is something wrong here? I would think with all the fancy 3d games I've seen my crappy little animation should be functional.

Answer (score 4):

3D games are not using `UIImageView`, they use `OpenGL`.

Judging from these:

[Virtual memory leak when using UIImageView setAnimationImages?](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/7546-virtual-memory-leak-when-using-uiimageview-setanimationimages.html)

[UIImageView setAnimationImages: leaks animation array](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=330)

The method itself is bugged. I suggest loading and animating the images yourself (create and manage an array of `UILayer`s or simply switch the `UIImage` for the `UIImageView`).

Comment: I realize they're using OpenGL, I guess what I meant is that its sad that its choking